# Seeing previous review actions

Tags: discussion, review-queues

In Suggested Edits review queue when you press "Reject" button you can sometimes see that this edit has already one rejection with some specific reason:

[image]

How does it affect your choice? Is it helpful? If yes, will it be introduced to other review queues, where possible, like Triage (seeing previous "Looks OK", "Requires Editing", "Unsalvagable")?

Also I can see one possible robo-reviewing strategy: always click "Reject" and if there is already one rejection, reject with the same reason, otherwise skip. Does somebody care about it?

Comment: In regards to robo-reviewing... the system introduces "fake reviews" into the mix occasionally to check that reviewers aren't just "robo-reviewing"... failing those you could well receive a warning from the system asking you to pay more attention, and if it continues you could potentially lose access to the review queue by the system (or my moderators) for a period of time. As a rule of thumb, don't follow the crowd, just go for what you think is the correct decision given what you're presented.

Comment: @Robert oh gawd - thanks for pointing that out - I'll edit my comment - it was to be "by" (obviously) but paws have a mind of their own when touch typing and the following letter after the space was "m" - guess the paw went its own way. That's my excuse anyway... and I'm sticking with it... can't let the humans really know they're ruled by puppies... oh no wait... I've said too much! :p